# Anyway to show monitoring charts time axis in Eastern time instead of UTC?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

I am using monitoring  or metric chats in Azure portal extensively. The time axis on chars are sown in UTC as pointed below. Is there any way to show timelines in EST (eastern time) ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The time on the display you show is already in local time, the designation on the bottom right tells you the time is UTC-04:00 which is Eastern time.  Hover over the data with your mouse and will the see that the latest time is close to your computer time.

Comment: Is there any portal setting that defines the time-zone of dates shown in the Portal?

Comment: @AllanXu It seems to be the computer setting.  I changed the timezone on my computer and refreshed a page and it reflected the computer timezone change.  If there is a way to override in the portal I have not seen it.